# How do I buy tickets for Can-Ar coach?

Tags: buses, ontario

I'm planning to take a [Can-Ar coach](http://www.can-arcoach.com/schedule-services) bus from Toronto to Moore Falls, Ontario.  [According to rome2rio, this costs around 55 CA$](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Toronto/Moore-Falls).

How do I buy a ticket?  Must I buy it in advance, or can I buy it on the bus?  What modes of payment are accepted (cash with change, cash with exact amount, debit, credit)?

I am unable to find this information on the Can-Ar coach website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi the page you linked to gives you the clues you need, but is not very clear.

For long distance coach bus travel it's usual to book in advance.

The can-ar coach schedule that includes Moore Falls lists agents where you can purchase tickets.

http://www.can-arcoach.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/HaliburtonLine.pdf

You can also make purchase tickets / make reservations via

https://canar.betterez.com/full-page/tickets/canar.betterez.com/4f8c6202d23b52c33400001a/en-US/4f8c6202d23b52c33400001c

I can't find any details about if you can pay the driver, however if you can then it is likely that it would be cash only.

You could call them and ask. As you are in Canada it's Toll Free: 1-800-387-7097